# tar command - how to extract one file to specific directory

Tags: tar, extract, aix

Is there a way to extract a single file from a tar file to a specific directory?
In fact, I am dealing with a `.tgz` file so, I am attempting something like this :

`gunzip -c mytargzfile.tgz | tar xvf - path/to/myfile -C /tmp`

In order to extract a file entry called `path/to/myfile` in `mytargzfile.tgz` to `/tmp` directory.

But this command fails as tar complains saying it can not find file named `-C` and `/tmp` in the archive. I tried switching `-C` option before `xvf` and it did not help either.

*Note that I am using AIX, and KSH*

Comment: can't you just use the -z file on tar and skip the gunzip step? -z tells tar to treat it as a compressed archive.  So you'd have `tar -xzvf mytargzfile.tgz -T path/to/myfile /tmp`

Comment: the version of tar that comes standard on AIX does not have the -z option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think The C option to tar should occur earlier in the command

```
tar -cvf - -C /tmp path/to.myfile
```

I imagine you could download, compile and install GNU tar into your ~/bin, which *might* make things a bit easier.

Comment: That, plus you need to use `-c` to use standard mode options. With `c`, the command line is parsed in BSD mode which doesn't support `-C`.

Answer (score 1):

That command worked for me fine as you said you tried with the `-C` first:  `tar -C /tmp -xvf`.  Maybe it's a bug in your tar version?

A little clunky, but there's always:

```
cd /tmp
gunzip -c /path/to/mytargzfile.tgz | tar xvf - path/to/myfile
```

I recommend installing GNU tar for yourself.  It's worth it just for the `-j` and `-z` options if nothing else, and is one of the first things I always do in a new Unix account.