# AIX 5.3 Tar - Exctact to a different directory

Tags: tar, aix

I am trying to extract a untar a file to a different directory on a AIX 5.3 box

```
tar -xvf -C /tmp/ ./MyFile.tar 
tar: -C: No such file or directory

tar -C /tmp -xvf ./MyFile.tar
Usage: tar {c|r|t|u|x} [ bBdDEfFhilLXmNopRsSUvw[0-9] ]

tar -xvf ./MyFile.tar -C /tmp/
tar: file -C: not present in archive
tar: file /tmp/: not present in archive
```

Note:

- Installing GNU tar is not an option
- I would prefer not to CD to the target dir first
- I have seen [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/199870/tar-command-how-to-extract-one-file-to-specific-directory) on SU

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>-C</kbd> option only applies when you create an archive, not when you restore it. Your only option is to cd into the directory to restore into first, like this:

```
( cd /tmp && tar -xvf /<pathToMyFile.tar>/MyFile.tar )
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with **tar**, so I used **pax**:

```
pax -rf <tarfile> -s/regexToInitialTargetDir/regexToFinalTargetDir/p
```

In my case this was the target was **/volume01/sotcha/** and I wanted to extract to **/home/sotcha/** so the regex part was

```
-s/volume01/home/p
```